# How to move both panels to the bottom in GNOME?

Tags: gnome-panel

As everyone will know, in Ubuntu GNOME by default there is a panel at the top of the screen with a set of menus and icons and also one at the bottom with the window list etc.

What I wanted to do was move both of these to the bottom , with the window list and the absolute bottom of the screen and the other panel just above it.

So I set the alignment of both panels to 'bottom' but this made the window list panel the highest up panel.

I fixed this by manually moving everything between the panels and swapping it over which was fine , until I restarted my computer which resulted in them being swapped back over , so the window list is now above the other panel.

Is there a way to permanently set the window list to be the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With both panels at the bottom try this:

1. Push <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor`
2. Navigate to `/apps/panel/general`
3. In the list on the right side, double-click on the `toplevel_id_list` item
4. Switch the two items using the Up/Down buttons (in my case I switched from `bottom_panel_screen0 top_panel_screen0` to `top_panel_screen0 bottom_panel_screen0`):

   [image]
5. Close the `gconf-editor`, log out and back in again.

Comment: I don't see this option in Ubuntu 12.10 which is running GNOME. ALT+Left mouse click drag works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just add the WindowLIst Applet to the bottom panel , (right-click on the bottom panel, add applet) and done.., you probably would want to put all of the top panel applets on the bottom one and remove the top panel

Answer (score 1):

If you press ALT while pressing the left mouse button on a panel you can drag it to any corner of the screen.

After some testing, the last panel that you drag to the bottom of the screen remains at the bottom. So just ALT+click on the window list, drag it to the top, drag it back to the bottom and it should stay there.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to 13.04 but I understand all this info works for 12.04 upwards for folks who have chosen to remain with gnome-panel [we knew all this info 2 years ago but many of us have now forgotten it].

It has all to do with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and left/right clicks in the right sequence.

- to drag icon-bar to bottom/left/right click <kbd>Alt</kbd> then left click and drag to bottom/left/right.

  Can also be done this way: place cursor on icon-bar/leftclick/click <kbd>Alt</kbd>/rightclick and pick properties/orientation.
- right-click on Applications or Places to access alacarte [main menu]
  to move things around say Terminal from Accessories to Office etc.. also new launcher with + new item
- to remove icon from bar: press <kbd>Alt</kbd> then hover on icon leftclick and immediately righclick Remove from panel
- or do more adding and removing hover on icon-bar and **leftclick/press <kbd>Alt</kbd>/rightclick** add to panel or Properties